# Get entry point assembly of an Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have a reporting service that reported the service's version. For normal services I can use `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`, but this doesn't work for Azure roles. How can I detect the version of the role?

Comment: `this doesn't work for Azure roles`.  Could  you supply more info about `doest work `.  Is there any exception or other useful info?

Comment: Because an Azure rol is hosted by another application, the entry assembly is not a managed assembly, so it returns `null`.

Comment: If it is resolved, please add as answer that will help more communities to get it.

Comment: I have created a custom attribute (applicable to assemblies only) that can be used to mark the entry assembly. This will only work if you control the entry assembly yourself, so it's not a really good solution, but it helps in my case.

Comment: If it is possible, please add an answer that will help more communities who face the same issu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a shared assembly, I have defined the following attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly)]
public sealed class EntryAssemblyAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

The same assembly also contains a helper class that determines the entry assembly and its version:

```
public static class EntryAssemblyHelper
{
    public static bool IsEntryAssembly(this Assembly assembly)
    {
         return assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EntryAssemblyAttribute), false).Any();
    }

    public static Assembly GetEntryAssembly()
    {
        return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SingleOrDefault(IsEntryAssembly);
    }

    public static Version GetEntryAssemblyVersion()
    {
        return GetEntryAssembly()?.GetName().Version;
    }
}
```

All my root assemblies now use the following line in the `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: EntryAssembly]
```

Although it requires some custom code it works well if all the entry assemblies in your system are your own. The major benefit of this solution is that it is unrelated to the bootstrapper, so it works with ASP.NET, Cloud Services and normal applications.